# Add to cart button not working on single product page in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with the add to cart button on the single product page in woocommerce. For some reason it will only add the product to the cart when a user is logged in. I've added a URL-based add to cart button labeled "No Ajax" which works but I'm not able to link the qty selector to the No Ajax add to cart button. The add to cart button on the archive page works just fine.

Here's the site with product example:
https://trudiesbridal-69ad6e.ingress-alpha.easywp.com/shop/bridal/wedding-dresses/dress-title-1/

I've attempted the following but no solutions found yet:
Deactivated all plugins
Cleared cache on site and computer
Clear woo transients and user sessions
Switched to Wordpress Theme 2020
Refreshed permalinks
Tested changes in chrome/incognito

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. As I assumed, it was a server caching issue with NameCheap. The caching plugin EasyWP was not letting the user add products to the cart from the single product page template.
The first 3 reps said the problem was on my end and kept asking me to clear browser cache. This solved nothing. After hours of failed research, I got on a chat for the 4th time with NameCheap which then led to them finding the issue in EasyWP.